# Cannot find 'kCIImageAccurateMetadata' in scope

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to use accent color for the background. I did properly linking to the required framework which is coreImage. but I am still getting  2 errors. Cannot find 'kCIImageAccurateMetadata' in scope and Cannot find 'CIDetectorTypeColor' in scope. I cleared the Xcode incase its a glitch but its not working at all. help needed.

```
 import SwiftUI
 import UIKit
 import CoreImage


class ColorExtractor {
var dominantColor: UIColor?

func extractColors(from image: UIImage, completion: @escaping ([UIColor]) -> Void) {
    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image) else {
        completion([])
        return
    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        let accuracy = [kCIImageAccurateMetadata: true]
        let colorDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeColor, context: nil, options: accuracy)!
        let features = colorDetector.features(in: ciImage)
        let colors = features.compactMap { feature -> UIColor? in
            guard let color = feature.color else { return nil }
            return UIColor(ciColor: color)
        }
        self.dominantColor = colors.first
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(colors)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is `CIDetectorTypeColor`? Cannot find any reference in the docs or by searching around 

Comment: Its a  detector that should identify regions of color in an image. To perform complex image analysis tasks, such as identifying faces and their skin colors. Its a part of coreImage Framework.

Comment: Can you please provide any source for this? I’m literally getting zero results regarding this…